# Repair missing keyframes in downloaded video stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I downloaded a video using ffmpeg with the following characteristics:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'video.ts':
  Duration: 00:27:59.76, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 714 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 640x360, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 67 kb/s
```

It has a little issue - if I seek through it, the picture looks like this:

[image]

I assume the reason is the missing keyframes. That problem is fixed with the following command

```
ffmpeg -i "video.ts" -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*3)" out.ts
```

But it re-encodes and re-sizes the file:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'out.ts':
  Duration: 00:27:59.77, start: 1.429089, bitrate: 547 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], max. 104857 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 123 kb/s
```

Appending `-c copy` to the above stated command doesn't change the file at all. Is it possible to keep the codecs and the quality and just to add keyframes? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to force keyframes the video must be re-encoded, so unless you specify that the video codec is h264 and the audio codec is aac, ffmpeg will encode the output in its default for the requested container format, in your case mp2.

As an alternative, if you don't need to stream the video then you can try to re-mux it as `.mp4`, you will solve the seek problem without transcoding at the expense on a less efficient seek.